# Python concept regarding lists and loops

Tags: python

I am lost as to why this function works the way it does.

```
a = [[0, 1, 2],
     [2, 3, 4],
     [4, 5, 6]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i == j:
            print(a[i][j])
```

The output for this function is:

```
0
3
6
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing to you? Which parts *do* you understand? Did you expect a different output and, if so, what? Also please note that code should be posted as **text**, not screenshots.

Comment: I tried posting it as text but then it just wouldnt let me do it. Maybe its my fault sorry I am very new to this I am just learning.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It may help you understand if you print out the values of `i` and `j` at each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Since the print statement only happens when `i == j`, we can simplify this code to just a single loop:

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i][i])
```

Then it's clear what's happening: it prints the elements from the diagonal, where the x and y coordinates are the same.

Answer (score 4):

It loops `i` from 0 to 2. For each `i`, it loops `j` from 0 to 2, too. Then it compares them and only prints out the item at `a[i][j]` if `i` and `j` are the same value. So the loops go like this:

```
i=0; j=0. Does i==j? Yes. Print a[0][0], which is 0.
i=0; j=1. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=0; j=2. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=1; j=0. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=1; j=1. Does i==j? Yes. Print a[1][1], which is 3.
i=1; j=2. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=2; j=0. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=2; j=1. Does i==j? No.  Do not print anything.
i=2; j=2. Does i==j? Yes. Print a[2][2], which is 6.
```

It's basically a really long-winded way of writing this.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(a[i][i])
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now! thank you so so so much this really really helped!

Comment: Like this answer.